# How can I test the availability of instance variables in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I'm using [decent_exposure](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure) to present some instance_variables :

```
expose(:my_custom_variable) { current_user.my_variable }
```

So now this variable is accessible within my controller as `my_custom_variable` .

But I would like to ensure it's there with my test.

```
assert_not_nil my_custom_variable
```

Which does not work. If I put a debugger in my test, there's no way for me to access this variable. I've tried all of the following..

```
@controller.instance_variable_get("@my_custom_variable")
@controller.instance_variable_get("my_custom_variable")
@controller.instance_variable_get(:my_custom_variable)
@controller.assigns(:@my_custom_variable)
assigns(:my_custom_variable)
@controller.get_instance(:my_custom_variable)
@controller.get_instance("my_custom_variable")
@controller.get_instance("@my_custom_variable")
```

None of this works.. Any ideas?

**Note:** I am not using rspec. This is built in rails functional tests.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is `decent_exposure` only assigns the local variable when the view is rendered? Although having looked over the docs, it seems this isn't the case

Comment: It uses helper methods, not instance or local variables. https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure/blob/master/lib/decent_exposure/expose.rb#L51-L62

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some examples on the decent_exposure page at the bottom.

Testing

Controller testing remains trivially easy. The shift is that you now set expectations on methods rather than instance variables. With RSpec, this mostly means avoiding assign and assigns.

```
describe CompaniesController do
  describe "GET index" do

    # this...
    it "assigns @companies" do
      company = Company.create
      get :index
      assigns(:companies).should eq([company])
    end

    # becomes this
    it "exposes companies" do
      company = Company.create
      get :index
      controller.companies.should eq([company])
    end
  end
end
```

View specs follow a similar pattern:

```
describe "people/index.html.erb" do

  # this...
  it "lists people" do
    assign(:people, [ mock_model(Person, name: 'John Doe') ])
    render
    rendered.should have_content('John Doe')
  end

  # becomes this
  it "lists people" do
    view.stub(people: [ mock_model(Person, name: 'John Doe') ])
    render
    rendered.should have_content('John Doe')
  end

end
```

Comment: with MiniTest or TestUnit it should be something like `assert_equal [company], controller.companies` i suppose

Comment: Did you manage it? Maybe you can include a simple but complete test example that works. So everybody has a TestUnit/Minitest solution to this problem =).

Comment: Yes it was actually just like you said. `@controller.my_custom_variable`

Comment: what about (minitest) `assert assigns :my_custom_variable` ?